# Django Nginx not working properly showing default page

Tags: django, nginx

I have an issue with ngnix on my site what I've just uploaded and configured on digitalocean.
The issue is that when I visit the site, I see the ngnix default page (at mydomain.net) but if I type mydomain.net/myapp I see my django app working. Everything works fine except the homepage.

I'm not sure what is this problem and I haven't find any solution for it online.
My site is on the latest django release and debud False. The domain is added to allowed_hosts and also in the ngnix config.

My urls:

```
url(r'^$',views.IndexLatest.as_view(),name='index'),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^meres/',include('myapp.urls')),
url(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
```

]

My config:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name bwalab.net;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/bwalab/bwalab;
}

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/bwalab/bwalab/bwalab.sock;
}}
```

And this is my nginx.conf

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }}
#
```

Does anyone have any idea what can be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: No, because you haven't shown any code. Where is the nginx configuration? What do your Django URLs look like?

Comment: Well, if it works on `mydomain.net/myapp`but not `mydomain.net`maybe you should check your nginx.conf and switch things around.

Comment: My bad, I've added my urls, and my conf file is under /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject, and linked to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled, and the default is deleted but somehow still showes up

Comment: How are you running your django process, generally a gunicorn or uwsgi process is used to run django's wsgi interface, which is then picked up by nginx. 

The setup should be something like `webbrowser -> nginx -> gunicon -> django.`

Comment: You can go over this tutorial follow from there: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I've followed this tutorial!

Answer (score -1):

i think you should **delete** the **default** configuration in **sites available** and your sites available configuration should be within the **sites enabled** directory as well.

```
/sites-available/
| 
|-> site.com
|-> site2.com
|-> disabled.com

/sites-enabled/  **this links to the files in /sites-available**
| 
|-> site2.com
|-> site2.com
```

Comment: I use a custom sites-available config that was working with django, but after installing nginx I see the default Apache page. My sites available should not need to change as it still looks like it did when I set it up to work with django.